# Why is wpa_cli producing error "Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: wlan0 - re-trying"?

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa

I am running `4.9.13-4-ARCH #1 SMP Sat Mar 11 14:16:01 MST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux` and I am using systemd-networkd for the network in conjunction with wpa_supplicant, obviously.

## Running `wpa_cli -i wlan0`:

```
wpa_cli v2.6
Copyright (c) 2004-2016, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.



Interactive mode

Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: wlan0 - re-trying
```

## Running `strace wpa_cli -i wlan0`

Suspicious Lines

```
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/tmp/wpa_ctrl_485-2"}, 110) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to specify explicitly the location of the control interface in the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf` file.

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
```

This adds a `wpa_supplicant` directory in two volatile directories:

1. `/run`
2. `/var/run`.

For a description of `/run` and `/var/run`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175349/33386.
Don't forget to run wpa_cli as root or add `ctrl_interface_group` to allow users of that group to call wpa_cli.

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant # set location of the control socket 
ctrl_interface_group=admin # group admin can use wpa_cli
update_config=1 # allows saving changes to file that are made in cli
```

Apparently the default location is not set to the actual location. (`/var/run/wpa_supplicant`) You need to set it manually in Arch Linux and perhaps others.

---

## Notes

The `GROUP=netadmin` parameter does not work on Arch Linux as on other distributions (or older versions?). If you use this, it will be included in the path of the `ctrl_interface` *because it gobbles up spaces*.

Comment: Just to reaffirm. You must include the `ctrl_interface` directive, which has the effect of wpa_supplicant spawning sockets which will receive connections. Telling `wpa_cli` the right socket path, is insufficient by itself

Comment: that is included in my startup and I'm still getting the same error. Nothing was created in /run or /var/run and no noticeable errors were produced